# OpenCv can't read small image

Tags: java, opencv

I have images with size 20x20, I can't read it by OpenCV. If I use image with size bigger, OpenCV can read it. What's the reason ?

[image: This is my test]

Comment: OpenCV does not support `.gif` image format. See supported [formats](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56).

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). See why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV does support `.gif`, but as a *video*. use `VideoCapture` for GIF, even if it's *not* an animated GIF.

be aware that OpenCV needs third party libraries to read images and video.